# My video player is not working in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I used the `video_player` package in flutter to make a UI, in which a button is in the middle of the screen, and used a logic to play video when it is tapped (and this will change the button from play to pause) and vice-versa. But my video is not playing, while button is still changing from play to pause whenever I tap on it. Last time it was working fine, but now it is only showing the first frame and nothing else is playing, just freezed. No error or exception is showed.

Here is my code -

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoEditingScreen extends StatefulWidget {

  final String path;
  VideoEditingScreen({Key key, this.path}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _VideoEditingScreenState createState() => _VideoEditingScreenState();
}

class _VideoEditingScreenState extends State<VideoEditingScreen> {

  VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _videoPlayerController = VideoPlayerController.file(File(widget.path))
      ..initialize().then((value) {
      setState(() {

      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.crop_rotate,
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.emoji_emotions_outlined,
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.title,
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.89,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.89,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              child: _videoPlayerController.value.isInitialized
                ? AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: _videoPlayerController.value.aspectRatio,
                child: VideoPlayer(_videoPlayerController),
              ) : Container(),
            ),
            Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
              child: Stack(
                alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.12,
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Row(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.black45,
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5.0, right: 20.0, bottom: 2.0),
                          child: TextFormField(
                            maxLines: 6,
                            minLines: 1,
                            textAlignVertical: TextAlignVertical.bottom,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            cursorColor: Color(0xFF075E54),
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              suffixIcon: CircleAvatar(
                                backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                                radius: 30.0,
                              ),
                              contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 17.0),
                              prefixIcon: Container(
                                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.075,
                                margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 8),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  border: Border(right: BorderSide(color: Color(0xFF074E54))),
                                ),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.add_photo_alternate,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
                                ),
                              ),
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              hintText: 'Add a caption...',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.grey[400],
                                fontSize: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.045,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.04,
                    left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.81,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF02877A),
                      radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.075,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.check,
                        color: Colors.white,
                        size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.07,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            InkWell(
              onTap: () {
                setState(() {
                  _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying
                      ? _videoPlayerController.pause()
                      : _videoPlayerController.play();
                });
              },
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.center,
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
                  radius: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.085,
                  child: Icon(
                    _videoPlayerController.value.isPlaying ? Icons.pause : Icons.play_arrow,
                    color: Colors.white,
                    size: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.12,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

An here is the run log -

```
D/AudioTrack( 7736): getTimestamp_l(32): device stall time corrected using current time 11138917046960
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7736): bufferpool2 0xec8a3788 : 4(32768 size) total buffers - 4(32768 size) used buffers - 0/5 (recycle/alloc) - 4/39 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7736): bufferpool2 0xec8993e8 : 4(32768 size) total buffers - 4(32768 size) used buffers - 0/5 (recycle/alloc) - 10/2124 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7736): bufferpool2 0xec887d88 : 4(32768 size) total buffers - 4(32768 size) used buffers - 0/5 (recycle/alloc) - 7/600 (fetch/transfer)
D/AudioTrack( 7736): stop(32): called with 32160 frames delivered
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7736): bufferpool2 0xec8993e8 : 4(32768 size) total buffers - 4(32768 size) used buffers - 0/5 (recycle/alloc) - 10/2124 (fetch/transfer)
D/BufferPoolAccessor2.0( 7736): evictor expired: 1, evicted: 1
D/AudioTrack( 7736): getTimestamp_l(32): device stall time corrected using current time 11215137849060
W/AudioTrack( 7736): Spurious audio timestamp (frame position mismatch): 4294967296, 11215137849, 11215137806, 4020000, 32160, 32160
W/AudioTrack( 7736): Spurious audio timestamp (frame position mismatch): 4294967296, 11305873576, 11305873550, 4020000, 32160, 32160
W/AudioTrack( 7736): Spurious audio timestamp (frame position mismatch): 4294967296, 11307927800, 11307927776, 4020000, 32160, 32160
W/AudioTrack( 7736): Spurious audio timestamp (frame position mismatch): 4294967296, 11309192551, 11309192517, 4020000, 32160, 32160
```

Answer (score 0):

```
recordedFile.saveTo(videoPath);
_controller = VideoPlayerController.file(File(videoPath));
// this delay is needed , it seams that the file loading takes a while
Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 1000));
_controller.initialize().then((_) => setState(() {
    controllerInitisialized = true;
}));
```

[check out the code in this example and apply lucasses solution https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59022](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/59022)

Comment: This worked for me, the delay I added (i think) it gives time to properly load the file or finish some initialisation

Comment: no it didn't work for me